# Android device on windows 8

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, windows-8, adb

I'm having a serious problem, i am trying for 2 days to simply add a device to ADB Android Debug Bridge.(from android sdk) and i can't do that, i've tried many "solutions" but none worked.

I have a project application working fine, on my Eclipse. My Operational System is Windows 8 Pro 64 bits. When i simple connect a Mobile Phone (SAMSUNG Android GT-S5301B with Android 4.0.3) to my computer, eclipse cannot find it, adb devices cannot find it too, no one can find it.

I've tried to intall the drivers from android-sdk/extras/google/usb-drivers but it told me that was already installed.

I cant understand why my OS cant recognize the phone, i tried enabling the USB Debugging in phone configurations, tried disabling it too, tried with MTB mode and MTC mode too.

I dont know what to do, i did spent 2 days triying all the things that i found, i really need a help, a rescue.

What i do?

Comment: There are special USB drivers for Samsung phones.  You can get them from the Samsung web site.  I don't know if they will solve the problem but it's worth a try.

Comment: To whomever voted this down.  Why?  Down voting a question without a reason is bad form.  This is a legitimate problem seen by many Android developers, and Paulo obviously spent some time trying to resolve the issue before asking the question.   [I upvoted it to compensate.]

Comment: @DaleWilson Thanks! Some people do weird things for no reason. But thanks anyway to upvoting it to 0 again. And yes you're right i did spend a lot of worktime to try to solve it and i still can't solve it. Im trying to download the Samsung KIES because my device model dont have a single driver for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download adb driver from samsung website or install samsung kies it will work.

Comment: i cant find the driver for my device on the samsung website but i'm downloading this "Kies" and i'll see if it will work.

Comment: THANKS!!! i did install the KIES and the Samsung USB Drivers that was included on the setup did worked!!! now i can see the mobile phone on all the lists !! very thanks!!